# Unable to enter directories in Finder after moving directories to NAS

Tags: finder, folders, extended-attributes

I have a NAS, which I use for storing my old photos. When *moving* the remainder of my 2016 photos, the following problem occurred, but without any error message during the move operation. The move operation was done by holding the <kbd>cmd</kbd>-button while dragging and dropping in Finder.
In Finder on OS X version 10.11.6, the directory looks like this:

[image: Directory listing in Finder]

Using Finder, I can enter directories like `2016-10-15`, but not the ones with different icons. `2016-11-27` is a directory, and `2016-12-01` should not be shown twice, but is a result of the erroneous move operation.

I have researched online to figure this out, but have not yet found a solution. One of the possible explanations was [extended attributes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10/what-does-the-mean-in-ls-l). I ran a `xattr -c *` to clear all of the attributes. This did remove the attributes, but didn't solve the problem.

I can enter the directories using Terminal.

```
machinename:2016 user$ ls -al 2016-11-27
total 34600
drwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff       264 24 Jan 21:18 .
drwxrwxr-x  1 user  staff      7606 16 Mar 20:14 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff   1339112 24 Jan 21:05 2016-11-27 08.47.29.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 user  staff  12069896 27 Nov 16:58 DSC_0151.JPG
```

Any other ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Emphasizing "moving" means: you moved the folders from the local Mac to the NAS share with cmd-shift?

Comment: @klanomath, yes exactly, moving (not copying) by holding the CMD-key while dragging and dropping in Finder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to find a solution using the following steps:

1) Took a complete backup of the main photo folder using `tar`.

2) Figured out which file types I had (while keeping in mind that `jpg` and `JPG` are not identical)

`find . -type f | awk -F . '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,":",$1}'`

3) Then copied the files using `rsync`, specifying each file type from the above result (it was the `2016`-folder that had issues, so I copied the files I positively knew I wanted to `2016-test`):

`rsync -zarv --include="*/" --include="*.AVI" --include="*.JPG"  --include="*.MOV" --include="*.jpg"  --include="*.mov"  --include="*.mp4"  --include="*.png" --include="*.ini" --exclude="*" 2016/ 2016-test/`

Answer (score 1):

From the symptoms you describe I suspect a damaged `.DS_Store` file in the parent folder.

Try deleting it while the folder is closed in the Finder. Close all open windows in the Finder, then in Terminal `rm .DS_Store` while in the directory. This should be the same directory you were in when you ran the command in your question. Now `open .` will open the directory in the Finder and all should be OK. If that doesn't work you could also try deleting the `.DS_Store` in the directory above.

If neither of those work then I would try copying the entire folder tree in Terminal using the `cp` command.

Comment: I tried to run a `find . -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete` in the parent directory, but this didn't work out. Copying the files in Terminal didn't either.

Comment: Try the `find` again and remove the `-type -f` since it may cause a problem. Note that you want to run it in the folder *above* the one that contains the problem folders

Comment: Thanks, Tony - I tried to run `# find . -name '.DS_Store' -delete -print` once again, and only got `./2016/.DS_Store` as the result (which means that the `-type f` worked previously)... I'm out of ideas.

Comment: What happens if you go in to one of the directories that won't open in the Finder in the shell and then go `open .` ?

Comment: It opens a new Finder window with the folder selected as an object within the parent directory - i.e. I can't see the contents of the directory in Finder.